# Interceptor with Spring REST service

Tags: java, spring, rest

> I have implemented a rest webservice using Spring.My RestController code is as given below.I have created the interceptor as you have suggested in the above post.I am able to get the rest response but the requests are not getting intercepted.Could you please help me figure out what's wrong with my code:`

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;
class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

       @Override
       public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
          registry.addInterceptor(new HandlerInterceptorAdapter() {

             Logger logger = LoggerFactory
                    .getLogger(WebConfig.class);
             @Override
             public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
                if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
                     logger.info("Request URL::" );
                   HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;
              //     Method method = handlerMethod.getMethod();
               /**    logger.info("{} - {} - method '{}' on controller '{}'",
                         request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURI(), method.getName(),
                         handlerMethod.getBean().getClass()
                   );*/
                   logger.info("Request URL::" + request.getRequestURL().toString()
                        + ":: Start Time=" + System.currentTimeMillis());
                }
                return true;
             }
          });
       }
    }
```

`

```
 @RestController
    @RequestMapping(/v1/search)
    public class RestController {   
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("repoService")
        private IRepoService repoService;
        private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( RestController.class );
        @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}" ,method = RequestMethod.GET)    

        public List<RepVO> getRepById(@PathVariable String id) 
            List<RepVO> repVOList = repoService.getRepById(id);
            logger.info("Response received");    

            return repVOList ;


        }


    }
```

> I have added config file as below.Still it's not working:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

       @Override
       public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
          registry.addInterceptor(new HandlerInterceptorAdapter() {

             Logger logger = LoggerFactory
                    .getLogger(WebConfig.class);
             @Override
             public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
                if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
                     logger.info("Request URL::" );
                   HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;
              //     Method method = handlerMethod.getMethod();
               /**    logger.info("{} - {} - method '{}' on controller '{}'",
                         request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURI(), method.getName(),
                         handlerMethod.getBean().getClass()
                   );*/
                   logger.info("Request URL::" + request.getRequestURL().toString()
                        + ":: Start Time=" + System.currentTimeMillis());
                }
                return true;
             }
          });
       }
    }
```

Comment: wouldnt it make more sense to use @ControllerAdvice and implement a ResponseBodyAdvice with that? there you have in my opinion a little bit more flexibility, and you can change the body of the response

Answer (score 1):

You need to annotate your config class with

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
```

And then scan package of config class with `@ComponentScan`

Comment: Thanks for the response.I added the annotations in my config class as updated in above query.It's still not working.Not Sure what could be the reason.

Comment: Did you add `@ComponentScan`?

Comment: I have added following in applicationContext.xml <context:component-scan base-package="abc.ccs.ddd*" />

Comment: Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: Are you using XML config or Java based config? applicationContext.xml is the only XML config?

Comment: I am using XML based config.I have web.xml,application-context-datasource.xml, applicationContext.xml and spring-rest-servlet.xml.I have used Java based config just for interceptors.Tried it out with XML based config too but nothing works.

Comment: If you mix XML and Java Config you need to import Java Config into XML. To do so, just declare your Java Config class as Spring bean in your XML, e.g. `<bean name="WebConfig" class="com.my.WebConfig" />`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I tried out the above steps with a simple sample interceptor project to see if I am able to intercept the http requests and it works.Not sure what's wrong with my current project .